# Random single core CPU spikes causing video lag

Tags: nvidia, 20.04, video

I just recently installed Ubuntu for the first time, 20.04.1 LTS, 64-bit, GNOME 3.63.3. No matter what I'm doing, no matter how mundane it may be, a single, seemingly random, core of my cpu will suddenly spike along with a video stutter.

CPU spikes shown in System Monitor:

[image: CPU spikes shown in System Monitor]

The audio keeps playing as normal, but it's especially noticeable when playing games or watching a YouTube video. Initially I thought it was my video drivers, and updating them seemed to help temporarily, but it eventually started stuttering again. Updating them again seemed to help slightly, but now it's just getting worse and worse.